# Laravel Elixir: Gulp watch fires without any interaction

Tags: gulp, laravel-5.1, gulp-watch

I have the following set up within the assets/sass folder:

```
app.scss
   - partials
        _settings.scss
        _main.scss
```

Now the issue is that when i run gulp watch, it runs all ok as a normal gulp, but then it just repeats the sass process, even when I have not touched anything, have anything in the files etc

It constantly runs the following over and over, sometime constantly or after a few seconds: The below is the loop thats is spat out within the terminal.

```
 [20:49:30] Starting 'sass'...
 [20:49:30] Running Sass: resources/assets/sass/app.scss
 [20:49:30] gulp-notify: [Laravel Elixir] Sass Compiled!
 [20:49:30] Finished 'sass' after 23 ms
```

Now doing several tests to see whats causing this, if i have DONT have any files with in the `partials` directory and just have code within the `app.scss`then the `gulp watch`runs and simply waits for changes.

But as soon as I add a file within the sass folder or in the partials folder the gulp watch runs as I would expect, BUT this then never stops running the script...

I am using a simple elixir set up, for now:

```
  elixir(function(mix) {
      mix.sass('app.scss', 'public/js/main.css');
  });
```

Any ideas why this is.

Running on a Homestead VM latest
Using latest elixir version
Laravel v.5.1.13

**EDIT: Update**

I was doing this outside the VM so thought to try to run this through the VM and it seems to be OK and run as expected...

Answer (score 0):

I am running this outside the VM and so when run within the VM its runs as expected. But i do get the `Error in plugin 'gulp-notify' not found: notify-send`error, but i can turn this off via adding `process.env.DISABLE_NOTIFIER = true;` to the top of the gulp file.